# 'display:flex' on DIV with SVG inside not displaying on iPhone, works with display block

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create a simple navbar with a icon on the left and a hamburger menu on the right. The hamburger menu has two states, opened and closed.

The hamburger menu consists of a wrapper div with two svg's. One is a hamburger icon, one is a closed hamburger icon. When you hit the button, javascript toggles a class called 'hamburger-closed' which will display none the correct svg, and when you hit it again, it toggles to the other svg etc.

It works completely fine on my PC and looks great. However, when I load the page on my iPhone, the hamburger CLOSED icon doesn't show. However, the weird thing is, if I open the menu, the closed state appears just fine? And if I close it again, the normal hamburger icon still doesn't show.

I noticed that if I change the wrapper div from 'display: flex' to 'display: block', it works fine.

I cannot for the life of me figure this out as it works completely fine on a desktop with responsive view.

Anybody got any idea whats going on?

[DESKTOP VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV7rQ.png)

[MOBILE VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmjP3.png)

HTML

```
<nav id="nav">
      <div class="container-stretch">
        <div class="nav">
          <div class="nav_logo" id="mainLogo">
            <img src="./assets/images/cole_type.png" alt="Cole Skate Logo" />
          </div>
          <div class="nav_hamburger" id="hamburger">
            <svg id="hamburger-closed" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 33 23"><defs><style>.a{fill:none;stroke:#d1898b;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:3px;}</style></defs><g transform="translate(1.5 1.5)"><path class="a" d="M4.5,18h30" transform="translate(-4.5 -8)"/><path class="a" d="M4.5,9h30" transform="translate(-4.5 -9)"/><path class="a" d="M4.5,27h30" transform="translate(-4.5 -7)"/></g></svg>
            <svg id="hamburger-open" class="hamburger-closed" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25.456" height="25.456" viewBox="0 0 25.456 25.456"><defs><style>.a{fill:none;stroke:#eedacb;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:3px;}</style></defs><g transform="translate(2.121 2.121)"><g transform="translate(7.071 -7.071) rotate(45)"><path class="a" d="M4.5,18h30" transform="translate(-4.5 -8)"/></g><g transform="translate(-7.071 14.142) rotate(-45)"><path class="a" d="M4.5,18h30" transform="translate(-4.5 -8)"/></g></g></svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

SCSS

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  padding: rem(33) 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.nav {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: rem(30);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  &_logo {
    height: 100%;

    img {
      max-height: 100%;
    }
  }

  &_hamburger {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 999999;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    svg {
      max-height: rem(20);
    }
  }
}

#mainLogo {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}

.opacity-0 {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}

.active-navbar {
  background: $main-bg;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
}

#hamburger-closed .a {
  stroke: #d1898b;
}

.hamburger-closed {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: IIRC Safari doesn't like nesting display: flex

Comment: It does the same on Chrome for iOS too

Comment: All browsers on iOS are basically Safari with different skins i.e. the underlying rendering engine is always webkit and not blink or gecko.

Comment: Oh okay! Well, what do you suggest doing?

Comment: Not nesting display: flex.

Comment: Is there a guide anywhere that I can see things to look out for with webkit?